# Create recurrence rule for event (RRULE) in Android programatically

Tags: android, icalendar, rrule

Is there a way of programmatically generating a rrule string for an event in Android?

I found the [RecurrenceEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/calendar/+/refs/tags/android-cts-verifier-4.0.3_r1/src/com/android/calendarcommon/EventRecurrence.java) class in the Android source that generates a String from its fields. However, it does not seem to be accessible.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the RFC5545, in the specific to:

- [RDATE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.2);
- [RRULE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3);

I'm currently looking for an easy way of creating recurrent events on Android's Calendar content provider. I'll edit my answer if I'll have more info to share.

Hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.0+, A recurring rule is stored inside the RRULE column in [`CalendarContracts.Events`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html).

See here on how to [Query](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) CalendarContracts and fetch that column of the event.

Comment: My goal is to create the content of the column myself, not just to retrieve it

Comment: How to show calendarview if we use calendar content view